# MySQL update event triggers insert

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Simply put, i have this following event which runs every 1 minute :

```
UPDATE ticket SET status ='4'
WHERE duedate <= now()
```

now i need to create a trigger to catch whenever that `update` occurs then `insert` the ticket's `ticketID` to a certain table along with `datetime` (kind of an activity table). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will useful for you........

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER Employee_Trigger
    -> AFTER UPDATE ON employee
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> INSERT into Employee_log
    -> (user_id, description)VALUES (user(),
    -> CONCAT('Id with ',NEW.id,' is modified ',
    -> ' from ',OLD.start_date, ' to ', NEW.start_date));
    ->  END$$
```

Pls refer this link (http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-update.shtml)